# SimpleDateFormat doesn't workiIn Java

Tags: java, date-conversion

I've  a date string like "Jan 11, 2017 2:08:00 AM". I want to convert this string  to Date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.   My Code sample is below

```
 SimpleDateFormat  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String dateStr= inSoya.get("selectedDate").toString(); //Jan 11, 2017 2:08:00 AM

            Date dd=formatter.parse(dateStr);// Error !
```

The excepiton is throwen at the last line where I am tring to parse.

Error Message is  : **Java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jan 5, 2017 2:08:00 AM"**

So what should I do  ?

Comment: You need to tell the date formatter what format the date is that it will be given, not the format of the date you want

Comment: Well , For example : incoming date is :  "Feb 1, 2013 2:00:00 AM" and my pattern is : "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a"   but it doesn't work.  Also I've tried  MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss aaa" but same result.

Comment: read the two existing questions that are tagged. They should help you find your answer.

Comment: Hi , find it thanks.